# Uk visitor visa sponsored by boyfriend?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, visa-sponsors

So my boyfriend and I met online and we’ve been dating since April 2020. We haven’t met yet because I’ve been working in the US as an au pair. I was supposed to go home to South Africa in July and he would’ve visited me in August but unfortunately due to covid-19 I had to extend my stay in the US. I will be going home in January and I plan on visiting him in Scotland in February. He will be paying for my trip and I will be staying with him for two months so that we can celebrate my birthday together. I doubt we’re going to go out that much because of covid-19 , if we do it will probably be just to see his family. How do I estimate how much my trip will cost when we (he) really won’t be spending any money out of the ordinary with my being there. Also how do I go about the visa process when I will not have proof that I have a job in South Africa. I am currently a student (online) at the London school of international business so this doesn’t help when trying to prove I will be returning to South Africa. Another concern I have is would I be allowed to list him as a sponsor along with his details (bank statements, proof of residence,etc) even though we haven’t met? It’s really been a tough year with covid and we’re really hoping to meet in feb, So any advice on how to make this possible would be great!

Comment: You are *allowed* to list him as your sponsor, however your application will have at least two big red flags that IMHO make it unlikely you’ll get a visitor visa: 1) you and your boyfriend have never met in person and 2) you have no ties to your home country. On the face of it you don’t meet the eligibility criteria https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/938632/visit-guidance-v10.0ext.pdf#page17, you would probably be better going back to your initial plan of your boyfriend visiting you in SA next year and applying to the UK after that

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What about family ties? Aside from a job everyone in my family is still in my home country. Also if I were to get a job in South Africa would that give me a fighting chance for a visa? (Whether it be a low paying job since I am still a student)

Comment: *Dependent* family and a job **before** you apply for a visa makes a stronger case. They will weigh up how likely you are to overstay in the UK; a job you’ve not yet started and family whom you’ve already spent months apart from and are happy to leave again for two months after only a month back home don’t seem very compelling to me. But no-one can give you a definite answer as to whether an application will succeed or not